# Translate array of countries from Countries Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of countries:

`Country.all.sort{ |c1,c2| c1[0] <=> c2[0] }`

How would I incorporate the `translations` method of the [Countries Gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries#country-info)? So if pass in a locale, I could get back an array of translated countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to fork the repository and add a method to return a list of translated names.

My fork: https://github.com/LostTie/countries

My pull-request: https://github.com/hexorx/countries/pull/130

Added the method `#all_translated(locale)` that returns a list of translated country names.

- The returned list is only an array of country name strings
- The returned list is alphabetized in the translated language
- Countries that are missing locales are dropped from the list

Example: `Country.translate_all('fr')` will give you an array of all countries that have the French localization available, in alphabetical order.

**Original Answer:**

```
translated_countries = []
Country.all.each do |c|
    translated_coutries << c.translations['fr'] # 'fr' for French
end

translated_countries.all.sort{ |c1,c2| c1[0] <=> c2[0] }
```

If that performs as you expect you can smash the do block down into a more elegant method using a proc or a few other ways that may suit your needs.

Comment: Ace, however, for this, I receive `undefined method `translations' for ["Andorra", "AD"]:Array` when I pass `I18n.locale.to_s` into `translations`

Comment: Ok, I just looked at the gem . . .  Do you actually need the country objects to work with, or do you literally want only the translated country names?

Answer (score 1):

```
locale = 'fr'
translate = ->(country) { Country.new(country[1]).translations[locale] }
Country.all.sort { |c1, c2| c1[0] <=> c2[0] }.map(&translate)
```

Please note Country.all returns an array of country names and alphas so we have to create a new Country instance from each alpha.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a gem for enumerations, for example: https://github.com/cassiomarques/enumerate_it, which provides I18n support.

Enumerations are created as classes:

```
class RelationshipStatus < EnumerateIt::Base
  associate_values(
    :single,
    :married,
    :widow,
    :divorced
  )
end
```

I18n lookup is provided on both `humanized` and `Enumeration#to_a` methods, given the hash key is a Symbol. The I18n strings are located on enumerations.'enumeration_name'.'key':

```
# your locale file
pt:
  enumerations:
    relationship_status:
      married: Casado
```